# Does Jacobian of curve characterize the curve?

Tags: algebraic-curves, jacobian

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $k$ be a field (if necessary algebrically closed).

For curves $C_1,C_2$ over $k$, if there Jacobian $J_1,J_2$ are isomorphic, then $C_1\cong C_2$？

Moreover what property do functor of taking Jacobian from category of curves to category of abelian varieities have？

Comment: I think not, see eg https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82173968.pdf .

Comment: What we do have is the [Torelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torelli_theorem)